# Symfony2 Parameter Or cache Issue

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony2 for my application and application working fine on windows but when i upload it to server(ubuntu 12.04 LTS) it gives following error :

```
  **[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "user_show".**
```

I have search it to my whole application I have never used a parameter named **"user_show"** although it is one of my template name but I cant find why this error occurs.

I thought it is of cache issue for this I disable **APC** and **Xcache** on server but still the problem is same then I install **xcache** only still no effect .

Answer (score 0):

Some one bundle use this parameter.
You should find all files, which contain "user_show".

Most likely you will need a file in "DependensyInjection" folder.

There you can found the paramener define.
You should add this parameter in yours config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear cache `php app/console ca:cl`
2. Regenerate bootstrap.php.cache by `php composer.phar update`
3. If your clearing apc from conslole it clears apc for console only so to do it globbaly try to: `sudo service apache2 restart`